# Sitecore LINQ Case-Sensitive Query

Tags: sitecore-api, indexing

This is my code for searching a data in the specified index:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Common.Constants.IndexNames.PlotTreeIndexName).CreateSearchContext())
{
    var plotTreeQuerable = context.GetQueryable<UserPlottedTreeSearchResultItem>()
        .Where(m => m.LatestVersion)
        .Where(m => m.TemplateId == new Sitecore.Data.ID(Common.Constants.TemplateIDs.UserPlottedTreePageTemplateId));

    List<UserPlottedTreeSearchResultItem> results = new List<UserPlottedTreeSearchResultItem>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<UserPlottedTreeSearchResultItem>();
        if (typeOfSearch.ToUpper() == Constants.SearchTerm.EmailAddress.ToUpper())
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.PersonEmail.Equals(searchTerm));
        }
        else if (typeOfSearch.Equals(Constants.SearchTerm.NameOfThePerson, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.PersonName.Equals(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var t in searchTerm.Trim().Split(' '))
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.PersonName.Contains(t) || m.PersonEmail.Contains(t));
            }
        }
        plotTreeQuerable = plotTreeQuerable.Where(predicate);
    }
    if (plotTreeQuerable.Count() > 0)
    {
        results = plotTreeQuerable.ToList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

The string in `m.PersonEmail` should be case-insensitive. I tried the following code with their respective results:

test search value: `test.Val`

sample dataset/list:

```
test.val
test.Val
Test.val
TEST.VAL
```

1. `predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.PersonEmail.Equals(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Result: only returns `test.Val`

2. `predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.PersonEmail.Contains(searchTerm))`

same result: (returns `test.Val`)

Any reason as to why my code doesn't work? it should return all data from the dataset/list. First code doesn't seem to respect the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

You should add a new filter solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory to convert everything to a lowercase , this should apply to index and query.

**Schema.xml**

```
<field name="Name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Where text_general type

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    tokenizerFactory="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Option 2**

The second option is that you can create a computed field for `PersonEmail` which will convert the value to lowercase and then you can match `PersonEmail` value to search value in lowercase.

In this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/create-a-computed-index-field.html), it is mentioned how we can create the computed fields.

Below are the sample code as well:

```
public class EmailLowercase : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Item item = (Item) (indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem);
        // null check on item
            if (item == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
        
       //retutn value=Get PersonEmail field and return in lower case.
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

and add below code in your solr config file

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
    <field fieldName="EmailLowercase">Name.ComputedFields.EmailLowercase, Name</field>
</fields>
```

Comment: hi, where can i find this?

Comment: your-solr-instance\server\solr\configsets\_default\conf\managed-schema

Comment: sorry im quite new. is solr automatically installed when you setup a sitecore proj? cuz i don't recall having this in my local machine

Comment: @Christian mostly it's in C: drive where you can find your SOLR directory named Solr or SOLR-{Version} folder.

Comment: hmm but for the index config files, i think it's using lucene. i found this tag under one of the fieldnames ```<analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer" />```

is it the same from what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You shouldn't manually edit the managed-schema file. It'd be overwritten by Sitecore when a schema population is performed.

Answer (score 1):

The default index field type in `Solr` is `tokenized` which means that it will split up the string in your index. So, we need to make that index type to be `untokenized` and index field needs to be treated as a regular string but not tokenized index.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery">
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" search:require="solr">
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
          </fields>
          </documentOptions>
          <fieldMap>
            <fieldNames>
              <field fieldName="email" returnType="string"   storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea with ContentSearch LINQ provider is to have readable queries that are serialized into Solr queries. Therefore all the native C# logic cannot be understood by Solr. Look in the `search.log` and verify what your query actually ends up being.

It's quite easy to make such mistakes with the ContentSearch LINQ implementation, so many people find it better to use the native SolrNet API instead, ensuring the query being performed is the expected one. However that requires a bit more knowledge about Solr.

In your example, it basically boils down to the field you've indexed and whether Solr treats is as case sensitive or not. A good practice is to ensure the content is indexed in a way that suits the queries you need to perform.

Comment: i see. yes, the content is indexed but it still doesn't work

Comment: Then it's probably something about the field types/configuration in Solr, like if you're using "text" or "string" field types. Try making the Solr query native in the Solr Query UI. Once you get the correct response there, you can mimic that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by making the index

`indexType="TOKENIZED"`

`<field fieldName="Email" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />`

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using ?